# What did Ant-Man steal from the Avengers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In *Ant-Man*, Hank Pym sends Ant-Man

> to the Avengers facility to steal technology needed for the raid on the Pym Tech facility. The small device is then added to the Pym network, arguably to distract the company from the upcoming sabotage. But then later we see the entire Pym building implode into what we might imagine to be the location of the device that was stolen from the Avengers facility.

**So what did Ant-Man steal from the Avengers? And what does it do?**

Comment: I can't work out if you're being ironic. I'm guessing the entire conversation went "hey, how are we gonna get this cameo arranged?", "Dunno. Hows about he has to go and collect a macguffin and Falcon is there and they fight?".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When Lang is on the plane, about to do the air drop, we get an explanation of what the device is, and why it’s needed:

> Hank: The final phase of your training will be a stealth incursion. You must retrieve this prototype of a **signal decoy**. It’s a device that I invented in my SHIELD days.
>
> Hope: **We need it to counteract the transmission blockers that Cross installed in the Futures Vault.**
>
> Hank: It’s currently gathering dust in one of Howard Stark’s old storage facilities in upstate New York. Should be a piece of cake.

The schematic that Hank shows Scott is labelled "Signal Decoy", which seems unusually vague:

[image]

Comment: @CodeMed none of that is explained in any way by the movie

Comment: @CodeMed : Well, it's called a "signal decoy". The only way a decoy could counteract "transmission blockers" is if the blockers actively target transmissions. Essentially the decoy distracts the blockers, thereby allowing your REAL signal to make it past the blockers.

Comment: @CodeMed that's the way I understand it, yes. The signal decoy is what allowed the guy in the van to hack into the facility's system.